# Apply CSS to all pages including http://url?/id=x

Tags: php, html, css

How to apply CSS stylesheet to all pages

http://URL/viewphone.php  (CSS Stylesheet applies)

http://URL/viewphone.php/?id=59 (CSS is not seen)

What changes can i make ?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the forward slash after .php, i.e. http://URL/viewphone.php?id=59 (

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

The page rendered without CSS due to the extra "/" in the link

http://URL/viewphone.php/?id=59 (CSS is not seen)

http://URL/viewphone.php?id=59 (CSS is seen NOW , without the / after .php)